# Elastic - How to group transactions for dot net APM services in elastic search kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

To group transaction there is no transaction_group_name field available as part of APm agent tuning or agent confirmation. Then How can we group transaction ? Is any pipeline available? Any other option.

Tried writing dissect on transaction.name with transaction name and set value for it. But no luck.